# What is super effective against rock type Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-series

I want to know what is super effective against rock type Pokemon and also what rock Pokemon is good against.

Comment: Serious lack of research effort...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Attack pros & cons**

Rock moves are super-effective against:

FIRE     ICE     FLYING  BUG

Rock moves are not very effective against:

FIGHTING     GROUND  STEEL

**Defense pros & cons**

These types are not very effective against Rock Pokémon:

NORMAL   FIRE    POISON  FLYING

These types are super-effective against Rock Pokémon:

WATER    GRASS   FIGHTING    GROUND  STEEL

**Dual-type attack pros & cons**

This chart shows the strength of the Rock type against every type combination. The fraction of damage a Rock type move will deal is shown - ½ means 50% damage (not very effective), 2 means 200% (super-effective) and so on.

http://prntscr.com/3a5b05

Source : http://pokemondb.net/type/rock

Hope it helped.